# How to have dynamic API endpoints in retrofit based on ids?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to be able to use a dynamic API endpoint URL to get specific data. I was already able to use a fixed URL in my `@GET("endpoint")`, which works,, but I don't know how to use it dynamically.

I set up my class as follows:

```
class WebService {
    private lateinit var api: MyApi

    init {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://myUrl.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        api = retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)
    }
    suspend fun getData(): MyResponse {
        return api.getData()
    }

    interface MyApi {
        @GET("/my/endpoint/1")
        suspend fun getData(): MyResponse
    }
}
```

How would I be able to reformat it so that I can make it `@GET("/my/endpoint/MY_ID")`?

Comment: i'm confused what jetpack compose has to do with this ? could you perhaps clarify why jetpack compose is giving you this problem but xml wouldn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    interface MyApi {
    @GET("/my/endpoint/{myId}")
    suspend fun getData(@Path("myId") myId:String): MyResponse
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do I need to add the @Path to all outer methods params that call getData? Or would String be enough?

Comment: @user21966091 Your code. Maybe you can try  @GET("my/endpoint/{myId}") It about your .baseUrl("https://myUrl.com/") end of line "/" is change everything.